# Ошибки в коде sql, помогите пожалуйста

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

Что пишу:

```
CREATE TABLE Gas_Suppliers (
  Supplier_ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  Name VARCHAR(255),
  Address VARCHAR(255),
  Contact_Person VARCHAR(255),
  Phone VARCHAR(20),
  Email VARCHAR(255)
);
```

Какая ошибка возникает:

```
Error at line 3/18: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_230100", line 797
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_SQL", line 1658
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_230100", line 782
ORA-06512: at "APEX_230100.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", line 2035
```

В чем может быть причина?

Comment: AUTO_INCREMENT  - это точно Oracle?

Comment: Уточняйте в таких вопросах конкретную СУБД, запрос может выглядеть по разному в таких случаях

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Оракле это будет выглядеть по-другому:

```
CREATE TABLE Gas_Suppliers (
  Supplier_ID INTEGER generated always as identity PRIMARY KEY,
  Name VARCHAR(255),
  ....
);
```